# Install linphone on kyocera e4610

Tags: applications, voip

Is there a way to install LinPhone on this android based flip? The other option would be "signal" as an alternative voip idea...
Let me know, David

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible just sign thought app with a test signature int should install via adb.

Is thought still having issues just rename the package to com.android.cts.linphone and thou should be fine.